# What tools can be used to monitor jms broker in GlassFish

Tags: jakarta-ee, glassfish, jms, monitoring, openmq

I use Open MQ GUI Administration Console (in Glassfish installation directory) and [QBrowser](http://sourceforge.net/projects/qbrowserv2/). Are any other tools to be considered?

Answer (score 0):

Glassfish uses "Open Message Queue" and it comes with a GUI admin tool plus a full suite of command line tools. You can find these in the Glassfish/imq/bin folder.

You can also use a 3rd party app if you wanted as well, you just need to supply the connection info.

Visit the Oracle GlassFish Server Message Queue 4.5 [Administration Guide](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18930_01/html/821-2438/index.html) for more info.

Comment: Anshu, I want to get more information about my broker - view msg information, broker state, broker host/port etc. So, e.g. my jms cluster has 3 broker and I want to monitor situation. Can OpenMQ do it?

Answer (score 0):

Starting with Payara 5 (fork of Glassfish 5) there is a new option for monitoring via a REST style api on top of JMX: https://blog.payara.fish/rest-monitoring-in-payara-server

To enable that go to Admin Console / Monitoring. Then you are able to use all the available MBeans.

For example to see number of messages currently in DMQ:

```
https://localhost:4848/rest-monitoring/rest/read/com.sun.messaging.jms.server:type=DestinationManager,subtype=Monitor
```